# Able to send messages but not receive from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Phone authentication, logging in, fetching all users and sending messages seems fine. But I'm not able to receive those messages from the other user. Where have gone wrong?

ChatActivity:

```
public class Chat extends AppCompatActivity {
Button addImage;
Button sendButton;
EditText messageArea;
ScrollView scrollView;
TextView name;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String MessageSenderId;
String MessageRecieverId;
DatabaseReference rootRef;
RecyclerView userMessageList;
private final List<Messages> messagesList = new ArrayList<>();
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private MessageAdapter messageAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_message);
    messageArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_message);
    scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    addImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_image);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

    name.setText((getIntent().getStringExtra("name")));

    userMessageList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.messageList);
    messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(messagesList);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    userMessageList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    userMessageList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    userMessageList.setAdapter(messageAdapter);

    rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    MessageSenderId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    MessageRecieverId = getIntent().getExtras().get("visit_user_id").toString();

    fetchMessages();

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });
}

private void fetchMessages() {
    rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
            messagesList.add(messages);
            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void sendMessage() {
 String messageText = messageArea.getText().toString();
 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText)){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Can't Send Blank Message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
     String message_sender_ref = "Messages/" + MessageSenderId + "/" + MessageRecieverId;
     String message_reciver_ref = "Messages/" + MessageRecieverId + "/" + MessageSenderId;

     DatabaseReference user_message_key = rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId)
                                                 .child(MessageRecieverId).push();
     String message_push_id = user_message_key.getKey();

     Map messageTextBody = new HashMap<>();
     messageTextBody.put("message",messageText);
     messageTextBody.put("seen",false);
     messageTextBody.put("type","text");
     messageTextBody.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
     messageTextBody.put("from", MessageSenderId);


     Map messageBodyDetails = new HashMap();

     messageBodyDetails.put(message_sender_ref + "/" + message_push_id,messageTextBody);
     messageBodyDetails.put(message_reciver_ref + "/" + message_push_id,messageTextBody);

     rootRef.updateChildren(messageBodyDetails, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
         @Override
         public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
             if (databaseError != null){
                 Log.d("Chat_Log", databaseError.getMessage().toString());
             }
             messageArea.setText("");
         }
     });
 }
}
}
```

jSon

```
 {
"Messages" : {
"8hbPUUlw39OABqmqSJ63BAHFjan2" : {
  "Savitha" : {
    "-L4Vrd8ZrlgX94RbAS6W" : {
      "from" : "8hbPUUlw39OABqmqSJ63BAHFjan2",
      "message" : "Hello",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1517748655103,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L4VrdyO1mdQdER9BuZ2" : {
      "from" : "8hbPUUlw39OABqmqSJ63BAHFjan2",
      "message" : "Nope?",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1517748658463,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L4WUkbKnBU5GLLUOK3R" : {
      "from" : "8hbPUUlw39OABqmqSJ63BAHFjan2",
      "message" : "Oops",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1517759171386,
      "type" : "text"
    }
  }
 },
 "Akash" : {
  "UXksdU8MBvMtO4Wsl9Bgg5JGsxI2" : {
    "-L4VpxxLm2WwN-yogzrL" : {
      "from" : "UXksdU8MBvMtO4Wsl9Bgg5JGsxI2",
      "message" : "Hello",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1517748215965,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L4VrZ6o7541T_gorBuB" : {
      "from" : "UXksdU8MBvMtO4Wsl9Bgg5JGsxI2",
      "message" : "Hiii",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1517748634453,
      "type" : "text"
    }
  }
},
"Savitha" : {
  "8hbPUUlw39OABqmqSJ63BAHFjan2" : {
    "-L4Vrd8ZrlgX94RbAS6W" : {
      "from" : "8hbPUUlw39OABqmqSJ63BAHFjan2",
      "message" : "Hello",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1517748655103,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L4VrdyO1mdQdER9BuZ2" : {
      "from" : "8hbPUUlw39OABqmqSJ63BAHFjan2",
      "message" : "Nope?",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1517748658463,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L4WUkbKnBU5GLLUOK3R" : {
      "from" : "8hbPUUlw39OABqmqSJ63BAHFjan2",
      "message" : "Oops",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1517759171386,
      "type" : "text"
    }
  }
},
"UXksdU8MBvMtO4Wsl9Bgg5JGsxI2" : {
  "Akash" : {
    "-L4VpxxLm2WwN-yogzrL" : {
      "from" : "UXksdU8MBvMtO4Wsl9Bgg5JGsxI2",
      "message" : "Hello",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1517748215965,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L4VrZ6o7541T_gorBuB" : {
      "from" : "UXksdU8MBvMtO4Wsl9Bgg5JGsxI2",
      "message" : "Hiii",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1517748634453,
      "type" : "text"
    }
  }
}
},
"Users" : {
"8hbPUUlw39OABqmqSJ63BAHFjan2" : {
  "Email" : "",
  "Name" : "Akash",
  "Quote" : "",
  "Status" : ""
},
"UXksdU8MBvMtO4Wsl9Bgg5JGsxI2" : {
  "Email" : "",
  "Name" : "Savitha",
  "Quote" : "",
  "Status" : ""
}
```

}
}

I guess there's something wrong with the database, like some error in the way I'm fetching it.

Screenshot - http://ibb.co/cwOQtx

Comment: You're ignoring `onCancelled`, which *may* give valuable information about why your app doesn't work. A simple implementation: `public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: No error... its not showing anything

Comment: Is your `onChildAdded` getting called at all? E.g. if you put a breakpoint in that method in the debugger, does the debugger stop on that line? If not, you're likely listening to the wrong path in the database. To help with that, edit your question to include a sample of the JSON at `rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId)`. Share as text please, no screenshots. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: look to my edited question

Comment: Thanks for that update. Did you also run the code in a debugger with a breakpoint in `onChildAdded`? Did that breakpoint get triggered?

Comment: Add breakpoints or logs, as stated. If nothing is graphically displayed, the problem is your XML

Comment: im still a beginner... can u tel me what exactly i should code in child added... sorry fr d trouble tho